# Css flexbox gutter with spacing

Tags: html, css, flexbox, tailwind-css, gutter

I'm trying to inline 3 items on 1 row. Every item must have a bit of space. The problem is when I add margin
the third item will wrap. I already tried to add negative margin 
to the parent but that's not working.

I made an example with my problem the example is using [tailwindcss](https://tailwindcss.com/):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="flex flex-wrap -m-2">
  <div class="bg-red-500 w-1/3 p-4 m-2">
    test
  </div>  
  
   <div class="bg-red-500 w-1/3 p-4 m-2">
    test
  </div> 
  
   <div class="bg-red-500 w-1/3 p-4 m-2">
    test
  </div> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I cannot remove `flex-wrap` because it has to wrap every 3 items, and I cannot use `padding`.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that your divs are 1/3 their parent's width, but then when you add the margin in there, the total width goes over 100%. Unlike padding, which is counted as part of the element's width, margin is *in addition to* the element's width.

So there's two possible solutions here. The first is to set the width as 1/3 the parent width minus the desired margin. Since you used `m-2` in your example, which appears to be `.5rem` according to Tailwind, we would double that number to account for margins on both the right and left sides of each box, and end up with this:

```css
.flex-wrap > div {
  width: calc(33.333333% - 1rem);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="flex flex-wrap">
  <div class="bg-red-500 p-4 m-2">
    test
  </div>
  <div class="bg-red-500 p-4 m-2">
    test
  </div>
  <div class="bg-red-500 p-4 m-2">
    test
  </div>
  <div class="bg-red-500 p-4 m-2">
    test
  </div>
  <div class="bg-red-500 p-4 m-2">
    test
  </div>
  <div class="bg-red-500 p-4 m-2">
    test
  </div>
</div>
```

If you don't like that, a second option that lets you keep a nice simple 1/3 width for each div is to use a border on each one that is the same color as the background color. Your design will necessitate if that is possible or not. Obviously if you have a background image or your divs are supposed to have borders according to the design then this may not work (though you could always nest divs to take care of the problem in the latter case).

```css
.flex-wrap > div {
  border: .5rem solid white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="flex flex-wrap">
  <div class="bg-red-500 w-1/3 p-4">
    test
  </div>
  <div class="bg-red-500 w-1/3 p-4">
    test
  </div>
  <div class="bg-red-500 w-1/3 p-4">
    test
  </div>
  <div class="bg-red-500 w-1/3 p-4">
    test
  </div>
  <div class="bg-red-500 w-1/3 p-4">
    test
  </div>
  <div class="bg-red-500 w-1/3 p-4">
    test
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do slight modification to your css.
Since parent width is 100% and each child width is 33.33%, it won't accommodate in one line along with margin included. Margins are on top of the element and so total width becomes > 100% and the last element is moved to new line.

So, we will use `calc` here. We need to have width in a way that margin can be accommodated. So, if width = calc(33.33% - 20px), it means, per div we have 20px space which can be used to give margins of 10px on each side. To maintain uniformity make sure margin given is 50% of the value you subtract from 33.33%.

Have updated the code (added a style tag and modified the css accordingly):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>
    .test {
      width: calc(33.33% - 20px);
      margin: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="flex flex-wrap">
  <div class="bg-red-500 test p-4">
    test
  </div>  
  
   <div class="bg-red-500 test p-4">
    test
  </div> 
  
   <div class="bg-red-500 test p-4">
    test
  </div> 
  <div class="bg-red-500 test p-4">
    test
  </div>  
  
   <div class="bg-red-500 test p-4">
    test
  </div> 
  
   <div class="bg-red-500 test p-4">
    test
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope if helps. Revert for any clarifications.

Answer (score 2):

If, like me, you don't like the idea of using `33.33333333% -1rem`, you can use a built-in flexbox property.

Simply set the rule `flex: 1 0 0;` for each of your items as shown in the snippet below.

The last `0` tells the flexbox to ignore the initial with of each item, then the `1` tells it to grow until it the items together reach the full width of the flexbox container. (The first `0` tells it to not shrink smaller than the text it contains.)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>
    .custom-flexbox-1 > div {
      flex: 1 0 0;
    }
    html {
      overflow: hidden;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="flex flex-wrap -m-2 custom-flexbox-1">
    <div class="bg-red-500 w-1/3 p-4 m-2">
      test
    </div>

    <div class="bg-red-500 w-1/3 p-4 m-2">
      test
    </div>

    <div class="bg-red-500 w-1/3 p-4 m-2">
      test
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about tailwind, but with vanilla CSS, I can achieve it **without the hack** `calc` simply by `flex: 1;` for each child and `margin-right` for `:not(:last-child)`

Of course I could make it done with CSS grid easily too (distributed evenly among items). In the case you know ahead of time that there will be only 3 columns, it could even be easier for grid:

```css
.container {
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
}
.child {
  background: blue;
  flex: 1;
}
.child:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

/* Grid way */
.container-grid {
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
}
.child-grid {
  background: blue;
}

/* Even be easier if you know ahead that there're only 3 items */
.container-grid-3 {
  background: red;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
.child-grid-3 {
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="container-grid">
  <div class="child-grid"></div>
  <div class="child-grid"></div>
  <div class="child-grid"></div>
  <div class="child-grid"></div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="container-grid-3">
  <div class="child-grid-3"></div>
  <div class="child-grid-3"></div>
  <div class="child-grid-3"></div>
  <div class="child-grid-3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will surely work in accordance with your link tag:

```
<div class="flex flex-wrap " style="justify-content: space-evenly;">
    <div class="bg-red-500 p-4 m-2 " style="width: 30%;">
      test
    </div>

    <div class="bg-red-500 p-4 m-2" style="width: 30%;">
      test
    </div>

    <div class="bg-red-500 p-4 m-2" style="width: 30%;">
      test
    </div>
  </div>
```

check:https://jsfiddle.net/sugandhnikhil/o62p7jez/

Comment: That's not the desired result. The width between the items should be constant.

Answer (score 1):

An option coud be to use transparent border instead margin and background-clip to avoid background drawn under the borders.

```css
.bg-red-500 {
  border: 0.5em transparent solid;
  background-clip: padding-box;/* do not draw me where borders stand */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="flex flex-wrap m-2">
    <div class="bg-red-500 w-1/3 p-4 ">
      test
    </div>

    <div class="bg-red-500 w-1/3 p-4 ">
      test
    </div>

    <div class="bg-red-500 w-1/3 p-4 ">
      test
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip
>
> The `background-clip` CSS property sets whether an element's background extends underneath its border box, padding box, or content box.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easier to achieve this through display grid this with [Tailwind - Gap](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/gap)

```html
<div class="grid gap-3 grid-cols-2">
    <div>01</div>
    <div>02</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In many cases you can achive this by using breakpoint dependent flex-wrap / flex-nowrap and only set "gap" when it is needed.

For example. On large screens you don't want to break lines and want to have gap between elements: `lg:flex-nowrap lg:gap-x-5 flex-wrap`

You can combine it in different ways to get the behaviour you want.